# How to add more than one label to Histogram automatically

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a huge data and I want to add two labels to the Histogram.
the problem here is that the labels are calculated and added automatically to the histogram. for example if I have the following Histogram:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 10], 20000], 20, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Rotate[Style[#1, Bold, 14], 90 Degree], 
     Above] &), 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, ColorData["Rainbow"][height]]]
```

[image]

In this Histogram, the Bars labels are calculated automatically. I want to add the percentage of each number at the top of the number. something like the following handmade Histogram :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got it:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 10], 20000], 20, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
     Column[{Rotate[Style[#1/20000. "%", Red], 90 Degree], 
       Rotate[Style[#1, Bold, 14], 90 Degree]}], Above] &), 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, ColorData["Rainbow"][height]]]
```