# How can I get Histogram to show the number of elements in its bins?

Tags: histograms

I'm just using `Histogram[data, 50]`. All the examples on the `Histogram` help page show show the number of elements when the cursor hovers over each bin. I've tried to use `Tooltip` but it just shows 50 (the number of bins) for every bin.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51075/how-to-add-more-than-one-label-to-histogram-automatically 
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50991/how-to-place-more-than-one-chartlabel-in-a-barchart

Answer (score 4):

LabelingFunction is your friend, see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelingFunction.html):

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500], 
 LabelingFunction -> Above]
```

[image]

You can also use ToolTipe like so:

```
Tooltip[Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
Histogram[data, 50, ImageSize -> 400, LabelingFunction -> Tooltip]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciated! Couldn't find it in my documentation search.

Comment: @user5091, glad I could help. Apparently there is some max number of bins beyond which tooltips are not shown.